# On demand docker containers creation/deletion

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

We want to scale docker containers horizontally based on user demand. Is there any docker api for on demand container creation/deletion, What can be the best approach for the use case given below.

Use case: 
We've a service running inside a docker container which is directly accessible to a user.
Each user will be given separate container, So we need to create docker container whenever user requests for service, Also we need to delete containers when they're idle for specific time period.

Comment: hey, did you find what you were looking for?

Comment: Docker engine seems good for our use case, we're also looking for other options i.e kubernetes

Comment: good to hear! Btw,  feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are looking for the **Docker Engine API**, which you can find [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/).

There is an SDK for **Go** and **Python** and a RESTful API for all others.

In the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/examples/) you find examples of how to start and stop containers programmatically.